# Integrate gaussian times sqare root of x times polynomial of order 2

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, symbolic-computation

How does one evaluate integrals like:
$$
\int_0^\infty{\sqrt{x}\,\dfrac{\left(x-a\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}\,\exp{\left(-\dfrac{\left(x-\mu\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}}\;dx
$$
There is a real and finite value, this can be shown by numerical integration but maxima, I and WolframAlpha struggle evaluating it symbolically.

Comment: I resisted down-voting this. Show an attempt at the solution. And more generally, why?? Do you have a use for this integral? If not, just take the numeric answer. From looking at it for a couple seconds, I'd guess statistics, and the Gaussian distribution will come into play.

Comment: Have you tried real mathematica(c)?

Comment: @Mark Fisher: I sadly do not have real mathematica.

Comment: @Zach466920 I want to calculate the Kullback–Leibler divergence of a measurement - this is one of the final integrals. I tried partial integration as I already know the integral of sqrt(x) times gaussian but it did not help either.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Now that I know what this is for, I'll upvote this.

Comment: @MarkFischler: I now do have mathematica 9 and maple 11 but they both fail to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188838), we have the following results, in terms of [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function),

depending on whether $\mu$ is positive or negative. But first, let us define the following three

quantities : $\color{green}A=\dfrac\mu{2\sigma}~,~$ $\color{green}P=\mu~\Big[2~\big(a-\mu\big)^2+3~\sigma^2\Big],~$ and $\color{green}Q=2\mu~\big(a-\mu\big)^2+\big(5\mu-4a\big)~\sigma^2.~$

Then, for $\color{blue}{\mu<0}$ we have $F~=~\dfrac{e^{-A^2}}{8\sigma^2}\cdot\sqrt{-\dfrac\mu2}~\cdot~\bigg[Q\cdot K_{\tfrac14}\Big(A^2\Big)-P\cdot K_{\tfrac34}\Big(A^2\Big)\bigg],~$ and

for $\color{blue}{\mu>0}~$ we get $$F~=~\dfrac\pi2\cdot\dfrac{e^{-A^2}}{8\sigma^2}\cdot\sqrt{\mu}~\cdot~\bigg\{P\cdot\bigg[I_{\tfrac34}\Big(A^2\Big)+I_{-\tfrac34}\Big(A^2\Big)\bigg]+Q\cdot\bigg[I_{\tfrac14}\Big(A^2\Big)+I_{-\tfrac14}\Big(A^2\Big)\bigg]\bigg\},~$$ whereas for $\color{blue}{\mu=0}$ we obtain $F~=~\dfrac{\big(2a^2+3\sigma^2\big)~\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac34\bigg)-a~|\sigma|~\sqrt2\cdot\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac14\bigg)}{4~\sqrt[\large^4]2~\sqrt{|\sigma|}}~.$

Answer (score 3):

There is, surprisingly, an easy way to do this using sums. Firstly, all I actually have to do is evaluate integrals of the form
$$ I(s,m) = 2\int_0^{\infty} y^{s-1} \exp{(-(y-m)^2)} \, dy: $$
your integral can be expressed in terms of a sum of integrals of this form, by scaling $y$ and substituting $m=\mu/(\sqrt{2}\sigma)$ and so on. So, first I expand the exponential and extract the $m^2$ term, leaving
$$ e^{m^2}I(s,m) = 2\int_0^{\infty} y^{s-1} e^{-y^2} e^{-2my} \, dy. $$
There is an obvious next step: expand the right-hand side as a power series in $m$. Interchanging the order of integration, we have
$$ e^{m^2}I(s,m) = 2\int_0^{\infty} y^{s-1} e^{-y^2} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} (2m)^k y^k \right) \, dy \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} (2m)^k \left( 2\int_0^{\infty} y^{k+s-1} e^{-y^2} \, dy \right) $$
The integral can be done by substituting $u=y^2$, $du/u=2dy/y$, which gives
$$ 2\int_0^{\infty} y^{k+s-1} e^{-y^2} \, dy = \int_0^{\infty} u^{(k+s)/2-1} e^{-u} \, du = \Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2}(k+s)\right)$$

It remains to do the sum,
$$ e^{m^2}I(s,m) = 2\int_0^{\infty} y^{s-1} e^{-y^2} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} (2m)^k y^k \right) \, dy \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2}(k+s)\right) (2m)^k $$
It is straightforward to turn this into a couple of [confluent hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) by separating the even and odd terms and playing with the $\Gamma$s using the duplication formula (I'll have a go if asked), to reach the final result
$$ I(s,m) = e^{-m^2} \left( \Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2}s\right) {}_1 F_1\left(\tfrac{1}{2}s;\tfrac{1}{2}; m^2 \right) -2m \Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2}(s+1)\right) {}_1 F_1\left(\tfrac{1}{2}(s+1);\tfrac{3}{2}; m^2 \right) \right), $$
where
$$ {}_1 F_1 (a;b;z) = \frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(a+k)}{\Gamma(b+k)} \frac{z^k}{k!}. $$

Comment: I'm seeking an approximation of the integral which like your integral
$$ I(s,m,a,b) = \int_a^b y^{s-1} \exp{(-(y-m)^2)}  dy $$
with $s \in \Bbb N^*$ and $a,b \in \Bbb R$. Could you please tell me whether this integral (or your integral) has a name? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I know this doesn't have a name, but standard saddle-point or endpoint expansions should work, depending on the order of $a,b,m$.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I found a semi-closed form expression for this integral. Indeed, it suffices to compute the integral $$J(t,m,a,b):= \int_a^b e^{ty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-m)^2}dy$$
which has closed form expression by using $Erf$ or $\Phi$ function.
After that, compute 
$$I(s,m,a,b) = \frac{d^s J}{dt^s}|_{t=0}$$